# Should a 'enter' pressed in a text field that has places autocomplete trigger a place_changed event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, google-places-api

Should the event handler for a place_changed for places autocomplete be triggering on the press of enter/return? I see the autocomplete answers but I'm not selecting any, I'm typing in my own string then I press enter, but the event "place_changed" is still triggered. Is this the default behavior? I don't want it to be...

Here I'm just entering in "some test fields" but the event is still firing
[image]

```js
var navbarInput = document.getElementById('searchQuery');
    var navbarOptions = {
        types: ['geocode']
    };
    var navbarAutocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(navbarInput, navbarOptions);

    // event here is still firing after I don't select an autocomplete answer and press enter
    google.maps.event.addListener(navbarAutocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var thisplace = navbarAutocomplete.getPlace();
        if (thisplace.geometry.location != null) {
            $("#latitude").val(thisplace.geometry.location.G);
            $("#longitude").val(thisplace.geometry.location.K);
            $("#mapType").val(thisplace.types[0]);
        }
        
        $("form").submit();
    });
```

Comment: Why would pressing 'enter' trigger a place_changed event. That's stupid! So now I'm triggering it even if there is nothing in the text field. It's empty! Shouldn't it only trigger when I've actually selected a autocomplete drop down item?

Comment: I agree it appears silly. Just disable the enter key if the field is in focus and empty.

Comment: but here is the problem, this text box is in a form and I want to submit this form on 'enter'. What's happening now is instead of the form submitting, it's entering the place_changed event.

Comment: You should add a listener for the place_changed event and just return before submitting the form if there's no selected place.